# Google Vision Api text detection layout information from bounding box

Tags: image-processing, ocr, google-vision

I am trying to use google vision api to perform OCR on my images. The Json Output to the API call returns recognized words with bounding box information.

Could someone please tell me how to use this bounding box information to do layout analysis of my image?

If there is a library which takes this as input and returns sentences instead of words?

```
{
  "description": "Ingredients:",
  "boundingPoly": {
    "vertices": [
      {
        "x": 14,
        "y": 87
      },
      {
        "x": 53,
        "y": 87
      },
      {
        "x": 53,
        "y": 98
      },
      {
        "x": 14,
        "y": 98
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "description": "Chicken",
  "boundingPoly": {
    "vertices": [
      {
        "x": 55,
        "y": 87
      },
      {
        "x": 77,
        "y": 87
      },
      {
        "x": 77,
        "y": 98
      },
      {
        "x": 55,
        "y": 98
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

For instance in the above json, the words 'Ingredients:' 'Chicken' are on the same line. Is there a library which can give me this information out of the box?

Image used for OCR [source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ImPd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try rotating the image using Word or any other tool which lets you rotate.
It yielded the right answer in my case i.s read everything in the row continuously.

Answer (score 1):

There are several [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) available to obtain sentences instead of words. There are also official available examples in github. For example you can see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/vision/detect) go language example files. `detect.go` contains the next function to output texts by blocks:

```
    // detectDocumentText gets the full document text from the Vision API for an image at the given file path.
func detectDocumentTextURI(w io.Writer, file string) error {
    ctx := context.Background()

    client, err := vision.NewImageAnnotatorClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    image := vision.NewImageFromURI(file)
    annotation, err := client.DetectDocumentText(ctx, image, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if annotation == nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "No text found.")
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Document Text:")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%q\n", annotation.Text)

        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Pages:")
        for _, page := range annotation.Pages {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "\tConfidence: %f, Width: %d, Height: %d\n", page.Confidence, page.Width, page.Height)
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "\tBlocks:")
            for _, block := range page.Blocks {
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "\t\tConfidence: %f, Block type: %v\n", block.Confidence, block.BlockType)
                fmt.Fprintln(w, "\t\tParagraphs:")
                for _, paragraph := range block.Paragraphs {
                    fmt.Fprintf(w, "\t\t\tConfidence: %f", paragraph.Confidence)
                    fmt.Fprintln(w, "\t\t\tWords:")
                    for _, word := range paragraph.Words {
                        symbols := make([]string, len(word.Symbols))
                        for i, s := range word.Symbols {
                            symbols[i] = s.Text
                        }
                        wordText := strings.Join(symbols, "")
                        fmt.Fprintf(w, "\t\t\t\tConfidence: %f, Symbols: %s\n", word.Confidence, wordText)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```